# Finding series convergence by using the Comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I want to find whether the Series diverges using the Comparison test
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2 - n}\right)  $$
would it be correct to compare it to $\left(\frac{n}{n^2}\right)$ so I would get
$$ \left(\frac{n+1}{n^2 - n}\right) \geq \left(\frac{n}{n^2}\right)  $$
and since
$$  \left(\frac{n}{n^2}\right) = \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)  $$
and $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is a harmonic series and is divergent so the original series also diverges?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @GregoryStory16 Many times it is easier to compute the limit
$$
\lim \dfrac{\frac{n+1}{n^2-n}}{\frac{1}{n}} = 1 \ne 0,\infty
$$

Comment: My guess is that you meant to write $n=2$ instead of $n=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. For me, it's simpler to use some elementary *asymptotic analysis*:

A polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term, hence
$$\frac{n+1}{n^2-n}\sim_\infty \frac n{n^2}=\frac1n,$$
which diverges.

Comment: I think that the way proposed by the asker is more than an intuition, it's a fine and rigorous solution by direct comparison test. The asymptotic analysis is intuitive if we don't refer esplicitely to limit comparison test.

Comment: I used this term only because the inequality wasn't proved (albeit it's not hard). And I refer implicitly to  a theorem of asymptotic analysis (didn't mean to give all details): two  series with asymptotically equivalent general terms both converge or both diverge

Answer (score 1):

Yes your way is fine, as an alternative we can use that

$$\frac{n+1}{n^2 - n}=\frac{n-1+2}{n^2 - n}=\frac{n-1}{n^2 - n}+\frac{2}{n^2 - n}=\frac1n+\frac{2}{n^2 - n}$$